# Join MySQL Tables: Display All Results From Right Table In One Row Of Left Table

Tags: mysql, join, view

Here is some data in table one (persons)

```
Person Table
person_ID | Name | Address
        1 | JC   | 303 Main Street
        2 | NM   | 444 Nowhere Drive
```

And table two (Attribute)

```
Attribute table
person_ID | attribute
    1     |   dog
    1     |   cat
    2     |  bearded
```

When I join the tables I get the following view:

```
person_id | name | attribute
    1     |  JC  |   dog
    1     |  JC  |   cat
    2     |  NM  |  bearded
```

Their is a duplicate row from the left table. It contains the same person_id etc. I want to combine the first two results into one row. Like this:

```
person_id | name | attribute | attribute
    1     |  JC  |   dog          cat
    2     |  NM  |  bearded       NULL
```

or this:

```
person_id | name | attribute 
    1     |  JC  |  dog, cat
    2     |  NM  |  bearded
```

Here is some of the code I have tried:

```
SELECT person.*,Attribute.att FROM `person`,`Attribute` 
WHERE person.`person_id` = Attribute.person_id 
AND name = "" group by person_id
```

Left Join

```
Select * from person AS P
LEFT JOIN Attribute AS N
ON P.person_id = N.person_id
```

Also tried inner join.

Comment: I can't drop any of the attributes. All of them need to be displayed. Group By only shows the first result from the Attributes table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a function [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) that lets you concatenate rows into a string.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT person.*, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(attribute SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM Attribute
    WHERE person.id = Attribute.person_id
) as attributes
FROM `person`
```

I don't have MySQL on this machine, so I apologize if there are minor mistakes.

Comment: Note that GROUP_CONCAT also has some ordering options in case it's important to you that the result be predictable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting an unrecognized column error in the where clause. Does not recognize "person_id"

Comment: Actually, that was my mistake. This worked perfectly. Has anyone told you that you are a genius today :)